# Laravel 4 form Date formatting

Tags: php, laravel

I am having  trying to retrive created at date from datebase on edit form: 
in database saved in timestamp format. how to retrive date in custom format

```
          {{ Form::text('project_start', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: Using `Form::model` ?

Comment: {{Form::model($client, array('method' => $formMethod, 'url' => $url, 'class' => 'form-horizontal',))}}

Answer (score 1):

You can define an Accessor method in your related model class:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return date("Y/m/d", strtotime($value));
}
```

More on [documentations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)